# Iterating through a Collection, avoiding ConcurrentModificationException when removing objects in a loop

Tags: java, collections, iteration

We all know you can't do the following because of `ConcurrentModificationException`:

```
for (Object i : l) {
    if (condition(i)) {
        l.remove(i);
    }
}
```

But this apparently works sometimes, but not always. Here's some specific code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Collection<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        l.add(4);
        l.add(5);
        l.add(6);
    }

    for (int i : l) {
        if (i == 5) {
            l.remove(i);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(l);
}
```

This, of course, results in:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
```

Even though multiple threads aren't doing it. Anyway.

What's the best solution to this problem? How can I remove an item from the collection in a loop without throwing this exception?

I'm also using an arbitrary `Collection` here, not necessarily an `ArrayList`, so you can't rely on `get`.

Comment: Note to readers: do have a read of http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html, it may have an easier way to achieve what you want to do.

Answer (score 1672, accepted):

[`Iterator.remove()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--) is safe, you can use it like this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

// This is a clever way to create the iterator and call iterator.hasNext() like
// you would do in a while-loop. It would be the same as doing:
//     Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();
//     while (iterator.hasNext()) {
for (Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    String string = iterator.next();
    if (string.isEmpty()) {
        // Remove the current element from the iterator and the list.
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Note that [`Iterator.remove()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--) is the only safe way to modify a collection during iteration; the behavior is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified **in any other way** while the iteration is in progress.

Source: [docs.oracle > The Collection Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html)

---

And similarly, if you have a `ListIterator` and want to *add* items, you can use [`ListIterator#add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#add-E-), for the same reason you can use `Iterator#remove` — it's designed to allow it.

---

In your case you tried to remove from a list, but the same restriction applies if trying to `put` into a `Map` while iterating its content.

Comment: What if you want to remove an element other than the element returned in the current iteration?

Comment: You have to use the .remove in the iterator and that is only able to remove the current element, so no :)

Comment: Be aware that this is slower compared to using ConcurrentLinkedDeque or CopyOnWriteArrayList (at least in my case)

Comment: @Josh It does work fine for me. Just using it now for a collection of WebElement objects.

Comment: Is it not possible to put the `iterator.next()` call in the for-loop? If not, can someone explain why?

Comment: It is possible to put another `iterator.next()` call in the for-loop, but you will also have to add another check using `iterator.hasNext()` to make sure you even have another element to retrieve.

Comment: Can anyone comment how good is this way of deleting an element from a list if my list has a million elements and there are lots of possibilities of running out of java heap space?

Comment: If it is a linked list you should be great. If it is an array list then you are in trouble

Comment: Iterator.remove() is an optional operation, so it is not necessarily safe (or implemented) for all container iterators

Comment: @GonenI It's implemented for all iterators from collections which aren't immutable. `List.add` is "optional" in that same sense too, but you wouldn't say it's "unsafe" to add to a list.

Comment: As of Java 8, this approach is built-in as `l.removeIf(i -> condition(i));`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29187813/929708

Comment: I'm using this approach and still get a `ConcurrentModificationException`. Can someone explain to me why this is?

Comment: @bill-k Why you verify if the string is empty? `if (string.isEmpty())`

Comment: @Quimbo it is just a condition...the example shown is to remove empty strings.  I didn’t write it, so many people have edited this question—look at the history for fun.  Personally I liked my original answer, it was like two lines, but I guess it’s important to be as clear as possible with such a popular answer

Comment: Is this still the recommended way in 2021?

Comment: @marticztn If you need to remove an object (or objects) from a collection inside a loop, then yes, however these days I would personally use the streaming api and filter it as the first step.  This leaves the collection untouched (So it doesn't solve the "Remove it" problem, but it does let you use the collection without that data), and you could collect it into a new collection perhaps.  This would be way less performant because it would make a copy of the entire collection, however the streaming API has some big benefits when it comes to threading--I guess it's up to you and your use case.

Comment: **Iterators** are not always helpful when another thread also modifies the collection. I had tried many ways but then realized traversing the collection manually is much safer (backward for removal)

Comment: @SaeedIr If you are reading from a different thread than you are modifying from,  you should be using one of the high-performance threadsafe collecitons instead.  You cannot ever trust "Manual" synchronization of threads, you must use java constructs to lock out other threads while you are modifying one--because of multiple CPUs and caching, how a normal collection works while being manipulated by another thread is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 360):

This works:

```
Iterator<Integer> iter = l.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    if (iter.next() == 5) {
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

I assumed that since a foreach loop is syntactic sugar for iterating, using an iterator wouldn't help... but it gives you this `.remove()` functionality.

Comment: foreach loop *is* syntactic sugar for iterating. However as you pointed out, you need to call remove on the iterator - which foreach doesn't give you access to. Hence the reason why you can't remove in a foreach loop (even though you *are* actually using an iterator under the hood)

Comment: +1 for example code to use iter.remove() in context, which Bill K's answer does not [directly] have.

Answer (score 243):

With Java 8 you can use [the new `removeIf` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-). Applied to your example:

```
Collection<Integer> coll = new ArrayList<>();
//populate

coll.removeIf(i -> i == 5);
```

A simple test as example:

```java
    @Test
    public void testRemoveIfOneList() {
        List<String> outer = new ArrayList<>();
        outer.add("one");
        outer.add("two");
        outer.add("three");

        outer.removeIf(o -> o.length() == 3);

        assertEquals(1, outer.size());
    }
```

It even works when you compare two lists and want to remove from both.

```java
    @Test
    public void testRemoveIfTwoLists() {
        List<String> outer = new ArrayList<>();
        outer.add("one");
        outer.add("two");
        outer.add("three");
        List<String> inner = new ArrayList<>();
        inner.addAll(outer);

        // first, it removes from inner, and if anything is removed, then removeIf() returns true,
        // leading to removing from outer
        outer.removeIf(o -> inner.removeIf(i -> i.equals(o)));

        assertEquals(0, outer.size());
        assertEquals(0, inner.size());
    }
```

**However, if one of the list has duplicates, make sure it's iterated in the inner loop**, because for inner list, it will remove **all** elements meeting the criteria, but for outer list, when **any element** is removed, it will return immediately and stops checking.

This test will fail:

```java
    @Test
    public void testRemoveIfTwoListsInnerHasDuplicates() {
        List<String> outer = new ArrayList<>();
        outer.add("one");
        outer.add("one");
        outer.add("two");
        outer.add("two");
        outer.add("three");
        outer.add("three");
        List<String> inner = new ArrayList<>();
        inner.addAll(outer); // both have duplicates

        // remove all elements from inner(executed twice), then remove from outer
        // but only once! if anything is removed, it will return immediately!!
        outer.removeIf(o -> inner.removeIf(i -> i.equals(o)));

        assertEquals(0, inner.size()); // pass, inner all removed
        assertEquals(0, outer.size()); // will fail, outer has size = 3
    }
```

Comment: Ooooo! I was hoping something in Java 8 or 9 might help. This still seems rather verbose to me, but I still like it.

Comment: Is implementing equals() recommended in this case too?

Comment: by the way `removeIf` uses `Iterator` and `while` loop. You can see it at java 8 `java.util.Collection.java`

Comment: @omerhakanbilici Some implementations like `ArrayList` override it for performance reasons. The one you are referring to is only the default implementation.

Comment: @AnmolGupta: No, `equals` is not used at all here, so it doesn't have to be implemented. (But of course, if you use `equals` in your test then it has to be implemented the way you want it.)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer now, this will be applicable and desirable for most people looking at the answers here.

Answer (score 44):

Since the question has been already answered i.e. the best way is to use the remove method of the iterator object, I would go into the specifics of the place where the error `"java.util.ConcurrentModificationException"` is thrown.

Every collection class has a private class which implements the Iterator interface and provides methods like `next()`, `remove()` and `hasNext()`.

The code for next looks something like this...

```
public E next() {
    checkForComodification();
    try {
        E next = get(cursor);
        lastRet = cursor++;
        return next;
    } catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        checkForComodification();
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
}
```

Here the method `checkForComodification` is implemented as

```
final void checkForComodification() {
    if (modCount != expectedModCount)
        throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
}
```

So, as you can see, if you explicitly try to remove an element from the collection. It results in `modCount` getting different from `expectedModCount`, resulting in the exception `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you! I often don't call remove() myself, I instead favour clearing the collection after iterating through it. Not to say that's a good pattern, just what I've been doing lately.

Answer (score 28):

You can either use the iterator directly like you mentioned, or else keep a second collection and add each item you want to remove to the new collection, then removeAll at the end. This allows you to keep using the type-safety of the for-each loop at the cost of increased memory use and cpu time (shouldn't be a huge problem unless you have really, really big lists or a really old computer)

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Collection<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Collection<Integer> itemsToRemove = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
        l.add(Integer.of(4));
        l.add(Integer.of(5));
        l.add(Integer.of(6));
    }
    for (Integer i : l)
    {
        if (i.intValue() == 5) {
            itemsToRemove.add(i);
        }
    }

    l.removeAll(itemsToRemove);
    System.out.println(l);
}
```

Comment: this is what i normally do, but the explicit iterator is a more elgant solution i feel.

Comment: Fair enough, as long as you aren't doing anything else with the iterator - having it exposed makes it easier to do things like call .next() twice per loop etc.
Not a huge problem, but can cause issues if you are doing anything more complicated than just running through a list to delete entries.

Comment: @RodeoClown: in the original question, Claudiu is removing from the Collection, not the iterator.

Comment: Removing from the iterator removes from the underlying collection... but what I was saying in the last comment is that if you are doing anything more complicated than just looking for deletes in the loop (like processing correct data) using the iterator can make some errors easier to make.

Comment: If it is a simple delete values that aren't needed and the loop is only doing that one thing, using the iterator directly and calling .remove() is absolutely fine.

Comment: using Iterator.remove() only works on the current value provided by the iterator. If you have some condition in your loop that requires removal of some _other_ member of the collection, then RodeoClown's solution is the way to go.

Answer (score 19):

In such cases a common trick is (was?) to go backwards:

```
for(int i = l.size() - 1; i >= 0; i --) {
  if (l.get(i) == 5) {
    l.remove(i);
  }
}
```

That said, I'm more than happy that you have better ways in Java 8, e.g. `removeIf` or `filter` on streams.

Comment: This is a good trick. But it wouldn't work on non-indexed collections like sets, and it'd be really slow on say linked lists.

Comment: @Claudiu Yes, this is definitely just for `ArrayList`s or similar collections.

Comment: I'm using an ArrayList, this worked perfectly, thanks.

Comment: indexes are great. If it's so common why don't you use `for(int i = l.size(); i-->0;) {`?

Answer (score 17):

Same answer as [Claudius](https://stackoverflow.com/a/223927/1433392) with a for loop:

```
for (Iterator<Object> it = objects.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    Object object = it.next();
    if (test) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

With [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/), the method `removeIf` defined on [MutableCollection](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections/blob/master/eclipse-collections-api/src/main/java/org/eclipse/collections/api/collection/MutableCollection.java#L236) will work:

```
MutableList<Integer> list = Lists.mutable.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
list.removeIf(Predicates.lessThan(3));
Assert.assertEquals(Lists.mutable.of(3, 4, 5), list);
```

With Java 8 Lambda syntax this can be written as follows:

```
MutableList<Integer> list = Lists.mutable.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
list.removeIf(Predicates.cast(integer -> integer < 3));
Assert.assertEquals(Lists.mutable.of(3, 4, 5), list);
```

The call to `Predicates.cast()` is necessary here because a default `removeIf` method was added on the `java.util.Collection` interface in Java 8.

**Note:** I am a committer for [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/).

Answer (score 11):

Make a copy of existing list and iterate over new copy.

```
for (String str : new ArrayList<String>(listOfStr))     
{
    listOfStr.remove(/* object reference or index */);
}
```

Comment: Making a copy sounds like a waste of resources.

Comment: @Antzi That depends on the size of the list and the density of the objects within. Still a valuable and valid solution.

Comment: I have been using this method. It takes a bit more resource, but much more flexible and clear.

Comment: This is a good solution when you are not intending to remove objects inside the loop itself, but they are rather "randomly" removed from other threads (e.g. network operations updating data). If you find yourself doing these copies a lot there is even a java implementation doing exactly this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html

Comment: Making a copy of the list is what they are typically doing with listeners on Android. It's a valid solution for small lists.

Answer (score 10):

With a traditional for loop

```java
ArrayList<String> myArray = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < myArray.size(); ) {
    String text = myArray.get(i);
    if (someCondition(text))
        myArray.remove(i);
    else
        i++;   
}
```

Comment: Ah, so its really just the _enhanced_-for-loop that throws the Exception.

Comment: FWIW - same code would still work after modified to increment `i++` in the loop guard rather than within loop body.

Comment: Correction ^:  That is if the `i++` incrementing were not conditional - I see now that's why you do it in the body :)

Answer (score 10):

People are asserting one **can't** remove from a Collection being iterated by a foreach loop. I just wanted to point out that is *technically* incorrect and describe exactly (I know the OP's question is so advanced as to obviate knowing this) the code behind that assumption:

```java
for (TouchableObj obj : untouchedSet) {  // <--- This is where ConcurrentModificationException strikes
    if (obj.isTouched()) {
        untouchedSet.remove(obj);
        touchedSt.add(obj);
        break;  // this is key to avoiding returning to the foreach
    }
}
```

It isn't that you can't remove from the iterated `Colletion` rather that you can't then continue iteration once you do. Hence the `break` in the code above.

Apologies if this answer is a somewhat specialist use-case and more suited to the original [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110404/remove-elements-from-a-hashset-while-iterating) I arrived here from, that one is marked as a duplicate (despite this thread appearing more nuanced) of this and locked.

Answer (score 5):

[ConcurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) or [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) or [ConcurrentSkipListMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html) may be another option, because they will never throw any ConcurrentModificationException, even if you remove or add item.

Comment: Yep, and note that those are all in `java.util.concurrent` package.  Some other similar/common-use-case classes from that package are `CopyOnWriteArrayList ` & `CopyOnWriteArraySet ` [but not limited to those].

Comment: Actually, I just learned that although those data structure Objects _avoid_ `ConcurrentModificationException`, using them in an _enhanced_-for-loop can still cause indexing problems (i.e: still skipping elements, or `IndexOutOfBoundsException`...)

Answer (score 4):

Another way is to use a copy of your arrayList just for iteration:

```java
List<Object> l = ...
    
List<Object> iterationList = ImmutableList.copyOf(l);
    
for (Object curr : iterationList) {
    if (condition(curr)) {
        l.remove(curr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: `i` isn't a `index` but instead the object. Maybe calling it `obj` would be more fitting.

Comment: Was already suggested above back in 2012:https://stackoverflow.com/a/11201224/3969362
Making a copy of the list is what they are typically doing with listeners on Android. It's a valid solution for small lists.

Answer (score 3):

A `ListIterator` allows you to add or remove items in the list.  Suppose you have a list of `Car` objects:

```
List<Car> cars = ArrayList<>();
// add cars here...

for (ListIterator<Car> carIterator = cars.listIterator();  carIterator.hasNext(); )
{
   if (<some-condition>)
   { 
      carIterator().remove()
   }
   else if (<some-other-condition>)
   { 
      carIterator().add(aNewCar);
   }
}
```

Comment: The additional methods in the [ListIterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) interface (extension of Iterator) are interesting - particularly its `previous` method.

Answer (score 2):

Now, You can remove with the following code

```
l.removeIf(current -> current == 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is too old to be about Java 8, but for those using Java 8 you can easily use removeIf():

```
Collection<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int i=0; i < 10; ++i) {
    l.add(new Integer(4));
    l.add(new Integer(5));
    l.add(new Integer(6));
}

l.removeIf(i -> i.intValue() == 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Java Concurrent Modification Exception**

1. Single thread

```
Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String value = iter.next()
    if (value == "A") {
        list.remove(it.next()); //throws ConcurrentModificationException
    }
}
```

Solution: iterator `remove()` method

```
Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String value = iter.next()
    if (value == "A") {
        it.remove()
    }
}
```

2. Multi thread

- copy/convert and iterate over another one collection. For small collections
- `synchronize`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59500618/4770877)
- thread safe collection[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65410514/4770877)

Comment: A condensed but more comprehensive answer.

Comment: Your first example is not equivalent to your second, or to the OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion for the problem above. No need of secondary list or any extra time. Please find an example which would do the same stuff but in a different way.

```
//"list" is ArrayList<Object>
//"state" is some boolean variable, which when set to true, Object will be removed from the list
int index = 0;
while(index < list.size()) {
    Object r = list.get(index);
    if( state ) {
        list.remove(index);
        index = 0;
        continue;
    }
    index += 1;
}
```

This would avoid the Concurrency Exception.

Comment: The question explicitly states, that the OP is not necessary using `ArrayList` and thus cannot rely on `get()`. Otherwise probably a good approach, though.

Comment: (Clarification ^) OP is using an arbitrary`Collection` - `Collection` interface does not include `get`.  (Although FWIW `List` interface does include 'get').

Comment: I just added a separate, more detailed Answer here also for `while`-looping a `List`.  But +1 for this Answer because it came first.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (Integer i : l)
{
    if (i.intValue() == 5){
            itemsToRemove.add(i);
            break;
    }
}
```

The catch is the after removing the element from the list if you skip the internal iterator.next() call. it still works! Though I dont propose to write code like this it helps to understand the concept behind it :-)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The best way (recommended) is use of `java.util.concurrent` package. By
using this package you can easily avoid this exception. Refer
Modified Code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Collection<Integer> l = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Integer>();
    
    for (int i=0; i < 10; ++i) {
        l.add(new Integer(4));
        l.add(new Integer(5));
        l.add(new Integer(6));
    }
    
    for (Integer i : l) {
        if (i.intValue() == 5) {
            l.remove(i);
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println(l);
}
```

Comment: Did you take into account the performance hit? Each time you "write" to this structure, it's contents will be copied to a new object. All this is bad for performance.

Comment: It isn't the best way and it isn't recommended. Don't use quote formatting for text that isn't quoted. If it is quoted, provide a citation.

Answer (score 0):

Example of thread safe collection modification:

```
public class Example {
    private final List<String> queue = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());

    public void removeFromQueue() {
        synchronized (queue) {
            Iterator<String> iterator = queue.iterator();
            String string = iterator.next();
            if (string.isEmpty()) {
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question assumes just a `Collection`, and not more specifically any `List`.  But **for those reading this question who are indeed working with a `List` reference, you can avoid `ConcurrentModificationException` with a `while`-loop (while modifying within it) instead if you want to avoid `Iterator`** (either if you want to avoid it in general, or avoid it specifically to achieve a looping order different from start-to-end stopping at each element [which I believe is the only order `Iterator` itself can do]):

***Update: See comments below that clarify the analogous is also achievable with the *traditional*-for-loop.**

```
final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
    list.add(i);
}

int i = 1;
while(i < list.size()){
    if(list.get(i) % 2 == 0){
        list.remove(i++);

    } else {
        i += 2;
    }
}
```

*No ConcurrentModificationException from that code.*

There we see looping not start at the beginning, and not stop at *every* element (which I believe `Iterator` itself can't do).

FWIW we also see `get` being called on `list`, which could not be done if its reference was just `Collection` (instead of the more specific `List`-type of `Collection`) - `List` interface includes `get`, but `Collection` interface does not.  If not for that difference, then the `list` reference could instead be a `Collection` [and therefore technically this Answer would then be a direct Answer, instead of a tangential Answer].

FWIWW same code still works after modified to start at beginning at stop at every element (just like `Iterator` order):

```
final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
    list.add(i);
}

int i = 0;
while(i < list.size()){
    if(list.get(i) % 2 == 0){
        list.remove(i);

    } else {
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Comment: This still requires very careful calculation of indicies to remove, however.

Comment: Also, this is just a more detailed explanation of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43441822/2308683

Comment: Good to know - thanks! That other Answer helped me understand that it's the _enhanced_-for-loop that would throw `ConcurrentModificationException`, but _not_ the _traditional_-for-loop (which the other Answer uses) - not realizing that before is why I was motivated to write this Answer (I erroneously thought then that it was _all_ for-loops that would throw the Exception).

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to rotate the list and remove the first element to avoid the ConcurrentModificationException or IndexOutOfBoundsException

```
int n = list.size();
for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
    //you can also put a condition before remove
    list.remove(0);
    Collections.rotate(list, 1);
}
Collections.rotate(list, -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one (removes all elements in the list that equal `i`):

```
for (Object i : l) {
    if (condition(i)) {
        l = (l.stream().filter((a) -> a != i)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while loop.

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    Map.Entry<String, String> entry = iterator.next();
    if(entry.getKey().equals("test")) {
        iterator.remove();
    } 
}
```

Comment: The point here is not the `while` loop but removing via the `Iterator.`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this `ConcurrentModificationException`, while iterating the list using `stream().map()` method. However the `for(:)` did not throw the exception while iterating and modifying the the list.

Here is code snippet , if its of help to anyone:
here I'm iterating on a `ArrayList<BuildEntity>` , and modifying it using the list.remove(obj)

```
 for(BuildEntity build : uniqueBuildEntities){
            if(build!=null){
                if(isBuildCrashedWithErrors(build)){
                    log.info("The following build crashed with errors ,  will not be persisted -> \n{}"
                            ,build.getBuildUrl());
                    uniqueBuildEntities.remove(build);
                    if (uniqueBuildEntities.isEmpty()) return  EMPTY_LIST;
                }
            }
        }
        if(uniqueBuildEntities.size()>0) {
            dbEntries.addAll(uniqueBuildEntities);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If using HashMap, in newer versions of Java (8+) you can select each of 3 options:

```
public class UserProfileEntity {
    private String Code;
    private String mobileNumber;
    private LocalDateTime inputDT;
    // getters and setters here
}
HashMap<String, UserProfileEntity> upMap = new HashMap<>();


// remove by value
upMap.values().removeIf(value -> !value.getCode().contains("0005"));

// remove by key
upMap.keySet().removeIf(key -> key.contentEquals("testUser"));

// remove by entry / key + value
upMap.entrySet().removeIf(entry -> (entry.getKey().endsWith("admin") || entry.getValue().getInputDT().isBefore(LocalDateTime.now().minusMinutes(3)));
```

Answer (score 0):

***Iterators*** are not always helpful when another thread also modifies the collection. I had tried many ways but then realized traversing the collection manually is much safer (backward for removal):

```
for (i in myList.size-1 downTo 0) {
    myList.getOrNull(i)?.also {
       if (it == 5)
          myList.remove(it)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In case **ArrayList:remove(int index)**- if(index is last element's position) it avoids without `System.arraycopy()` and takes not time for this.

arraycopy time increases if(index decreases), by the way elements of list also decreases!

the best effective remove way is- removing its elements in descending order:
`while(list.size()>0)list.remove(list.size()-1);`//takes O(1)
`while(list.size()>0)list.remove(0);`//takes O(factorial(n))

```
//region prepare data
ArrayList<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> toRemove = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Random rdm = new Random();
long millis;
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    Integer integer = rdm.nextInt();
    ints.add(integer);
}
ArrayList<Integer> intsForIndex = new ArrayList<Integer>(ints);
ArrayList<Integer> intsDescIndex = new ArrayList<Integer>(ints);
ArrayList<Integer> intsIterator = new ArrayList<Integer>(ints);
//endregion

// region for index
millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (int i = 0; i < intsForIndex.size(); i++) 
   if (intsForIndex.get(i) % 2 == 0) intsForIndex.remove(i--);
System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - millis);
// endregion

// region for index desc
millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (int i = intsDescIndex.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
   if (intsDescIndex.get(i) % 2 == 0) intsDescIndex.remove(i);
System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - millis);
//endregion

// region iterator
millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (Iterator<Integer> iterator = intsIterator.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); )
    if (iterator.next() % 2 == 0) iterator.remove();
System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - millis);
//endregion
```

- for index loop: 1090 msec
- for desc index: **519** msec---the best
- for iterator: 1043 msec

Answer (score -2):

you can also use **Recursion**

Recursion in java is a process in which a method calls itself continuously. A method in java that calls itself is called recursive method.

Answer (score -3):

this might not be the best way, but for most of the small cases this should acceptable:

> *"create a second empty-array and add only the ones you want to keep"*

<sub>I don't remeber where I read this from... for justiness I will make this wiki in hope someone finds it or just to don't earn rep I don't deserve.</sub>